# SignatureDoesNotMatch error when performing get request on URL from AWS S3 getSignedUrl in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im trying to access data I put using the `getSignedUrl` method from AWS.S3 API http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property . When I use the url returned by the method I get an error.

Code for putting data in S3 bucket

```
    var params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: 'testing132',
      Body: 'tasdfasfasdfs',
      Expires: EXPIRATION_TIME,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    $log.info('test s3 dep', this);

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      return cb(null, url);
    });
```

When performing GET request from POSTMAN on the returned URL I receive the following page with some info removed for security

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAJ.....</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>GET


1467833494
x-amz-acl:public-read
x-amz-security-token:FQoDYXdzEKz//////////wEaDBW+iL+gqGBqn2qxcyKcA1etzJzOZV33H3ND2hxQcm5MsJuZiHuEz5EvODXvDD7IfnlsbgNmLs70WAJ.................=
/s3test_test/testing132</StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>sNNramN6fDo+sf......=</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 34 36 37 38 33 33 34 39 34 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 ..............</StringToSignBytes>
    <RequestId>2404FC0B........</RequestId>
    <HostId>u5CapGu...............=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was some confusion, I didn't read the documentation carefully enough. I assumed that the 'putObject' argument in `getSignedUrl` method mean that I was uploading an object to the specified key and then retrieving a url to that object. This assumption was wrong, basically the `putObject` parameter means that your specifying the characteristics of an object that the user is PUTTING to the generated url. Using `getObject` solved the problem. From docs `You can use this functionality [putObject] to generate pre-signed PUT operations that require a specific payload to be uploaded by the consumer of the URL.`